# Proving a property of an operator norm on a linear map.

Tags: analysis

If A is a linear map $A:R^n \rightarrow R$ and $Ax=a\cdot x$. Show that $\|A\|=\|a\|$ where $\|a\|$ is the Euclidean norm.

So from the definition of an operator norm we have that $\|A\|=sup \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$ and $Ax=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...a_nx_n$. I've tried directly substituting everything into the equation but can't think/see how to simplify it to reach the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a=0$, done. Suppose $a\neq 0$

$\|Ax\|^2=\|a\cdot x\|^2\le \|a\|^2\|x\|^2$. Then $\|Ax\|\le\|a\|\|x\|$, so $\dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\le\|a\|$, thus $\|A\|\le\|a\|$.

If we exhibit an $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\dfrac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}=\|a\|$, we done.

Take $x_0=a$: $\dfrac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}=\dfrac{\|Aa\|}{\|a\|}=\dfrac{\|a\|^2}{\|a\|}=\|a\|$